# XSD import statement error

Tags: c#, xsd, dataset

i see the following squiggly 
[image]

What is this indicating ? I am trying to load a dataset through this XSD and there i believe since the imports are not getting resolved this is causing me a lot of trouble ?

Also the larger problem i have is that i have a bunch XSD Schemas which i need to convert into JSON equivalent.They have dependent xsd:import statements , what would be the best way of going about this in .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by going into the Security tab and selecting the suggested radio button "This is a full trust application". i used the following reference 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/b1db5b9f-50a4-4a21-aba1-afeb30957efd